# SQL query for EXCEPT or NOT IN

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists, except, sql-in

I'm new to SQL and I am trying to write a query on PostgreSQL to find the **cust_ID** and **customer name** of each customer at the bank who only has a loan at the bank, and no account.

The database schema is:

[image]

The results should have only these 3 customers:

[image]

My two attempts for this query are:

1)

```
(SELECT DISTINCT borrower.cust_ID, customer_name
FROM borrower, customer
where borrower.cust_ID = customer.cust_ID)
except
(SELECT DISTINCT cust_ID, account_number
 FROM depositor)
```

Where my output is:

[image]

2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT borrower.cust_ID, customer_name
FROM borrower, customer
WHERE (borrower.cust_ID = customer.cust_ID) NOT IN (SELECT cust_ID 
                                                    FROM depositor)
```

output is:
*ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = character varying
LINE 3: where (borrower.cust_ID = customer.cust_ID) not in (select c...
^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 117*

Please help me get this query right! Thank you!

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question

Comment: Please don't use images. However, "NOT ON" is not valid SQL...

Comment: got it! I will edit my question with the codes. thanks

Comment: the clause is `IN`and not on

Comment: I reposted with my codes

Comment: NOT IN will work for this.  As you're learning, you'll see it's more flexible to do a left join and test if the join failed.   Have fun with SQL!

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` to apply the logic that you want:

```
SELECT c.cust_id, c.customer_name
FROM customer c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM borrower b WHERE b.cust_id = c.cust_id)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM depositor d WHERE d.cust_id = c.cust_id);
```

Or with `IN` and `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT cust_id, customer_name
FROM customer 
WHERE cust_id IN (SELECT cust_id FROM borrower EXCEPT SELECT cust_id FROM depositor);
```